# Android Error while generating signed APK

Tags: android, key, apk, signing, dexguard

When I Build APK or generate signed APK. I get the following error. Any solution please ?

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexguardRelease'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't read [D:\Android Project\LOANWARE2\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-release.ap_(;;;;;;!**/*~,!/LICENSE,!***/./**,!**/picasa.ini,!/META-INF/NOTICE,!**/.svn/**,!**/.*,!***/_/**,!/LICENSE.txt,!**/SCCS/**,!/META-INF/LICENCE,!/NOTICE.txt,!**/about.html,!**/thumbs.db,!/META-INF/LICENSE.txt,!/NOTICE,!**/CVS/**,!**/package.html,!/META-INF/NOTICE.txt,!**/overview.html,!org/w3c/dom/*,!org/w3c/dom/ls/*,!org/xml/sax/**,!org/xmlpull/v1/**,!org/json/JSON*,!org/apache/commons/logging/Log.class,org/apache/http/Consts.class,org/apache/http/HttpHeaders.class,org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.class,org/apache/http/util/Args.class,org/apache/http/util/Asserts.class,org/apache/http/util/CharsetUtils.class,org/apache/http/util/NetUtils.class,org/apache/http/util/TextUtils.class,!org/apache/http/*,!org/apache/http/auth/*,!org/apache/http/auth/params/*,!org/apache/http/client/*,!org/apache/http/client/entity/*,!org/apache/http/client/methods/*,!org/apache/http/client/params/*,!org/apache/http/client/protocol/*,!org/apache/http/client/utils/*Utils.class,!org/apache/http/conn/*,!org/apache/http/conn/params/*,!org/apache/http/conn/routing/*,!org/apache/http/conn/scheme/*,!org/apache/http/conn/ssl/*,!org/apache/http/conn/util/*,!org/apache/http/cookie/*,!org/apache/http/cookie/params/*,!org/apache/http/entity/*,!org/apache/http/impl/*,!org/apache/http/impl/auth/*,!org/apache/http/impl/client/*,!org/apache/http/impl/conn/*,!org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/*,!org/apache/http/impl/cookie/*,!org/apache/http/impl/entity/*,!org/apache/http/impl/io/*,!org/apache/http/io/*,!org/apache/http/message/*,!org/apache/http/params/*,!org/apache/http/protocol/*,!org/apache/http/util/*,com/guardsquare/dexguard/runtime/***,!com/guardsquare/**,!**/dexguard.pro,!lib/*dictionary*.txt,!com/saikoa/**.properties,!proguard/**.properties,META-INF/services/**,!META-INF/**,!.hg**,!**/.hg**,!.git**,!**/.git**,!.svn**,!**/.svn**,!CVS,!CVS/**,!**/CVS,!**/CVS/**,!.cvsignore,!**/.cvsignore,!SCCS,!SCCS/**,!**/SCCS,!**/SCCS/**,!**.orig,!**~,**.class,lib/*/*.so,res/raw/*.so,assets/**.so,!**.so,!.readme,!**.keep,!**.DS_Store,!**.aidl,!**.rs,!**.rsh,!**.d,!**.java,!**.scala,!**.scc,!**.swp,!**.bak,!**thumbs.db,!**picasa.ini,!**package.html,!**overview.html,!**.AIDL,!**.RS,!**.RSH,!**.D,!**.JAVA,!**.SCALA,!**.SCC,!**.SWP,!**.BAK,!**THUMBS.DB,!**PICASA.INI,!**PACKAGE.HTML,!**OVERVIEW.HTML)] (Can't process XML file [AndroidManifest.xml]: file appears to be in binary XML format. Please check if you have included a default DexGuard application configuration. (Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.))

Answer (score 0):

try this one in your app/build.gradle file

```
android{
...
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

...
}
```

you can also exclude other files mentioned in error

Comment: Any Solution for this?